# getting parent element's index in xml and php?

Tags: php, xml, curl, parent-child

I am trying to get the parent element, I think of an XML tag. Basically I need to go through multiple `<HotelRoomResponse>` results and find this parent tag that contains a child tag with this exact number value:  `<roomTypeCode>17918</roomTypeCode>` I am not sure how to do this or what would be the best way. Because I then need to get ALL the information in that specific `<HotelRoomResponse>`. Here is an example XML response:

```
<HotelRoomResponse>
    <cancellationPolicy> </cancellationPolicy>
    <rateCode>200482409</rateCode>
    <roomTypeCode>17918</roomTypeCode>
    <rateDescription>
       Deluxe Sunset View - All Inclusive-Up to $300Resort Credit
    </rateDescription>
    <roomTypeDescription>
       Deluxe Sunset View - All Inclusive-Up to $300Resort Credit
    </roomTypeDescription>
    <supplierType>E</supplierType>
</HotelRoomResponse>
```

So there are various of these result types and I need to loop through it and find this specific one.

Here is how I am connecting to the XML:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
$fp = fopen('room_request.xml','w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?cid=55505&minorRev=13&apiKey=4sr8d8bsn75tpcuja6ypx5g3&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/535.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/17.0.963.79+Safari/535.11&customerSessionId=&xml=<HotelRoomAvailabilityRequest><hotelId>".$hid."</hotelId><arrivalDate>05/14/2012</arrivalDate><departureDate>05/18/2012</departureDate><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>3</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>0</numberOfChildren><childAges>0</childAges></Room></RoomGroup><includeDetails>true</includeDetails></HotelRoomAvailabilityRequest>");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
$val = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);//Close curl session 
fclose($fp); //Close file overwrite 
$avail = simplexml_load_file('room_request.xml');
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You should regenerate your API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out!!!! Here is what I used to get a node with text = value. Then I got all sibling elements.

```
// load as file
$contents = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);
$result = $contents->xpath('HotelRoomResponse[roomTypeCode="17918"]');

foreach($result as $key=>$node)
{
  $cancelPolicy = $node->cancellationPolicy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('room_request.xml');

/* Search for <HotelRoomResponse><roomTypeCode> */
$result = $xml->xpath('/HotelRoomResponse/roomTypeCode');
```

Result will give you a list of nodes you can then check and get the parent node if appropriate

see here http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Edit 2.
Key was the namespace

```
   <?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
$fp = fopen('room_request.xml','w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://travellinginmexico.com/test/room_request.xml");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
$val = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);//Close curl session 
fclose($fp); //Close file overwrite

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('room_request.xml'));

/* Search for <HotelRoomResponse><roomTypeCode> */
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/');
$result = $xml->xpath("HotelRoomResponse[child::roomTypeCode[text() = '153725']]");
foreach($result as $obj=>$node)
{
    var_dump($node->roomTypeCode);
}
```

With the example you sent will get specific information

Comment: sorry variable name kindly edited  and I put a slash in front of HotelRoomResponse

Comment: is the xml provided the full example??

Comment: no here is the url visible right now... http://travellinginmexico.com/test/room_request.xml

Comment: I can get the results with this:
$avail = simplexml_load_file('room_request.xml');
foreach($avail->HotelRoomResponse as $work){
 echo $work->roomTypeCode;
 }

Comment: but I need to get the one with text 17918 and then get the parent element and then get all of its nodes.

Comment: Using the example provided I have edited the answer - just substitute bits you need change then the $node variable will contain all the bits you need I believe

Answer (score 0):

To find all `HotelRoomResponse` nodes which has a `roomTypeCode` child node with the value `'17918'`, use the following:

```
$match = $avail->xpath("/HotelRoomResponse[child::roomTypeCode[text() = '17918']]");
```

EDIT: $match will be an array holding all matches.

Comment: Also did not work, gave me an array of 0.. do you think you could give me a little more of an example? I tried placing it in a foreach loop and nothing. I am not sure what is happening here. Thanks!